# C Custom Binary Search not following Multiple Of Element Size rule and crashes

Tags: c, crash, binary-search, string-comparison

It works perfectly fine for the first 2 elements but the third element gives problems.

I'm working with a `char **` where every element is a pointer to full string.

Lets say


Element 1 Pointer = `12273436`

Element 2 Pointer = `12273440`

When attempting to insert Element 3 using `BinarySearch` below. 

The `mid` becomes `12273438` which looks pretty fine but as you can see the pointers follow a `4 byte` rule per element. So cutting it short `2 bytes` crashes the program when it attempts to do the `CompareFunc`.

Here is a simulation.
`LowerBound = 12273436`
`UpperBound = 12273440`
`ElementSize = 4`

`mid = 12273436 + 4 * (12273440 - 12273436) / 4 / 2`

 `mid = 12273438` now

Here is a self contained code that runs.
http://ideone.com/RXU3o3

Here is the source code

```
int __cdecl BinarySearch(int ElementToFind, int Array, unsigned int TotalElements, unsigned int ElementSize, int (__cdecl *CompareFunc)(int, int), bool *IsFoundPointer)
{
    int mid; // esi@1
    int result; // eax@1
    int LowerBound; // ebp@2
    int UpperBound; // edi@2

    mid = 0;
    result = 0;
    *IsFoundPointer = false;
    if ( !TotalElements )
        return result; //NULL
    LowerBound = Array;
    UpperBound = Array + ElementSize * (TotalElements - 1);

    while ( 1 )
    {
        mid = LowerBound + ElementSize * (UpperBound - LowerBound) / ElementSize / 2;
        result = CompareFunc(ElementToFind, mid);
        if ( result < 0 )
        {
            if ( mid == Array )
                return mid;
            UpperBound = mid - ElementSize;
            if ( LowerBound > UpperBound )
                return mid;
        }
        if ( result <= 0 )
            break;
        LowerBound = mid + ElementSize;

        if ( LowerBound > UpperBound ) {
            if ( result > 0 )
                mid += ElementSize;
            return mid;
        }
    }
    *IsFoundPointer = true;
    if ( mid == Array ) {
        return Array;
    } else {
        while ( 1 )
        {
            mid -= ElementSize;
            if ( CompareFunc(ElementToFind, mid) ) //ElementToFind != mid element.
                break;
            if ( mid == Array )
                return Array;
        }
        return mid + ElementSize;
    }
    return result;
}

int __cdecl StringCompare(int ElementString, int ArrayPointer)
{
  printf("Element = %s Array = %s\n", (const char *)ElementString, *(const char **)ArrayPointer);
  return stricmp((const char *)ElementString, *(const char **)ArrayPointer);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be trying to pass a pointer as an integer (see how `ArrayPointer` is declared as an `int` but you are casting it to a `char **`. You are then manipulating the integer with the binary search. This is why you are getting whacky results.

Instead, you want either to:

- Pass 3 arguments to `StringCompare`: the address of the array (which can be treated as an opaque pointer passed from `BinarySearch`, and two integer offsets within that array; or
- Pass 2 arguments to `StringCompare` which are each `void *` pointers, which `BinarySearch` can calculate using `ElementSize`, the pointer to the array, and the offset.

The first is cleanest in my opinion, and doesn't require you to pass `ElementSize` at all, either to `BinarySearch` or (in turn) to `StringCompare`, as in each case it can work them out.

For instance:

```
int StringCompare (int element1, int element2, void *opaque)
{
    char *s1 = ((char **)opaque)[element1];
    char *s2 = ((char **)opaque)[element1];
    return stricmp(s1, s2);
}
```

Fixing up the binary search is left as an exercise for you, but it shouldn't require any pointer arithmetic at all.

**EDIT:**

Whilst the passing of pointers as integers (amongst other things - see `int_ptr_t` if you really want to do that) makes me deeply suspicious of the code, I suspect the problem is this line:

```
mid = LowerBound + ElementSize * (UpperBound - LowerBound) / ElementSize / 2;
```

and that the compiler is evaluating that left to right, so multiplying by `ElementSize` before dividing by it.

Try:

```
int midoffset = (UpperBound - LowerBound) / ElementSize / 2;
mid = LowerBound + ElementSize * midoffset;
```

Comment: That's the thing BinarySearch is decompiled from another application and it should work as it is. It should in my opinion work by pointers as well as elements which it gets re-used in other areas.

Comment: Why would it have ElementSize? isn't that strictly for pointer size?

Comment: I have no idea, but this line `mid = LowerBound + ElementSize * (UpperBound - LowerBound) / ElementSize / 2;` is deeply flawed as it allows `mid` to point to the middle of an item if `(UpperBound - LowerBound)` is an odd multiple of `ElementSize`. If you can't change that code, you appear to be stuck.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to change I figured out the problem it doesn't get multiple's of 4 and I don't understand how it used to work before. You ever worked with `IDA PRO?` want to take a look at the raw result? Here it is: http://i.imgur.com/kgW48tM.png

Comment: @SSpoke See my edit above - I suspect that's the cause of the problem. But, without being rude, I'd suggest it's a pretty awfully written bit of code anyway.

Comment: Thank You I'll try the midoffset solution, Yeah it could be a 
PEMDAS problem that's what IDA PRO got wrong. Yeah I can't really mess with the code too much as the `CompareFunc` later on gets replaced with a integer version and used on numbers instead of strings. I'm not a math person so I can't tell heads from tails whats going on.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! WORKS PERFECTLY NOW! with this code `mid = LowerBound + ElementSize * ((UpperBound - LowerBound) / ElementSize / 2);`, EDIT: okay so some elements get lost haha but atleast it doesn't crash.